# comparing file with program output using diff bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare contents of a file with program (`$1`) output, however the script doesnt do anything (just keeps running). If instead of `<($1 $file)` I use another file it works fine. I don't know what am i doing wrong here.

```
for file in $2/*.in
do
    if diff ${file%in}out <($1 $file) >/dev/null; then echo "something."; else echo "something2."
    fi
done
```

Also is there a way to store the output of `($1 $file)` in a variable or something?

When I compare same files (`${file%in}out`) I get:

```
something
something
something
```

(I have 3 in files and 3 out files)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you edit the question to include the errors you get?  Also, what does it look like when you _use another file_ and it works?

Comment: Remove the space after `<`, as in `<($1 $file)`.  Get your script checked at [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net).

Comment: Well i did that and now my script just keeps running and doesn't do anything. @codeforester

Comment: DO NOT CHANGE YOUR QUESTION. If you need to edit, add the new information at the bottom of your question -- otherwise, none of the comments (or answers) before your last edit will make sense.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't know

Comment: You get a free pass this time, just add at the end in the future `:)` Also, your problem is elsewhere. Removing the `space` fixed your syntax issues. Meaning (example), `diff myfile <(cat myfile)` will work fine. if `${file%in}out` describes a file and `$1` is a valid executable that can be found *In your path*, then your `diff` command should work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work then? I mean the $1 executable works fine?

Comment: If you don't need to see which lines have changed, and just want to know if the two files are the same, use `cmp` instead of `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `$1` command print anything to standard out, or only write a new .out file?

Here's my small test to illustrate the point:

```
## sanity check, have a diff
date > date.out
sleep 1
diff date.out <(date) 

## no diff 
writedate() { date > date.out; sleep 1; }
writedate
diff date.out <(writedate) # no diff

## overwrites the files, but still get a diff
writedate() { date | tee date.out; sleep 1; }
writedate
diff date.out <(writedate)
```

If that is the case, you can make a copy of the original file to be diffed before running the command and compare that

```
cmd=$1
indir=$2
for file in $indir/*.in; do
    outfile=${file%in}out
    prevoutfile=$outfile.old
    mv $outfile $prevoutfile
    $cmd $file # creates $outfile
    if diff $prevout $outfile >/dev/null; then 
      echo "something.";
    else
      echo "something2."
    fi
    mv $prevoutfile $outfile
done
```